# Can I create a report file that is readable by Tableau (or any other reporting tool) from my custom utility?

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, report, tableau-api

I've written a small utility that lets users use a proprietary interface for generating reports. However, I was wondering if there is some way, I can export my custom reports into some other reporting tool? Like say, the user generates a report with a chart using my utility, and then exports this into a different reporting tool, and then uses the GUI of that tool for further processes?

I have tried exploring Tableau as they have an SDK that provides a feature to generate .tde files. However, these files are basically just a custom data source at best and not actual reports. I am also exploring SSRS for the same. Is there any other tool that you can suggest which I should explore?

I am sorry if this is too vague at this point, but I am still trying to figure out how to go on about it.